# Qual significado da expressão usada no meio jurídico "tomar por termo"

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões-idiomáticas, significado-em-contexto

Eu tenho conhecimento que "reduzir a termo" significa registrar por escrito algo que está sendo comunicado de forma oral.

Porém, em muitas petições jurídicas, eu encontro a expressão "tomar por termo", que não parece ter o mesmo uso.

Um exemplo comum é na Petição de Primeiras Declarações de inventário, quando o requerente, após listar os bens do falecido, pede ao juiz "sejam tomadas por termo estas declarações".

O significado de registrar por escrito não se aplica, já que a petição é um documento formal, escrito.

Vocês poderiam me ajudar a entender o significado de "tomar por termo" neste contexto?

Comment: Quer dizer oficializar ou documentar. As declarações podem ser feitas por fulano, isto não significa que foram aceitas oficialmente pela tribunal. O peticionante (pelo advogado) justamente está fazendo esse pedido ao tribunal. Ou seja: que venham a fazer parte formalmente dos autos.

Answer (score 1):

Declarações feitas por testemunha são apresentadas por um advogado em um tribunal.

Aqui temos uma petição pedindo algo ao juiz.

. [Jurídico, Jurisprudência]  Qualquer declaração escrita nos autos. [O Aulete diz a mesma coisa]

"termo", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://dicionario.priberam.org/termo [consultado em 26-04-2019].

Também,no Aulete se le: Jur. Limite de prazo para cumprimento de condições, decisões etc.

Aqui não se trata de este significado.

A petição ao Tribunal (juiz) dará como resultado autos do procedimento formalmente. "Que os toma por termo": quer dizer que o juiz os considera como as declarações a serem incluidas nos autos e como a declarações escritas do requerente.

tomar algo por algo em português significa: julgar ou considerar (Aulete)

Answer (score -1):

significa transcrito e assinado.

Comment: Bem vinda ao site. É desejável que as respostas contenham referências para a gramática ou outros recursos online e bibliográficos que forneçam aos futuros leitores fundamentação teórica ou prática. Por favor edite a resposta para enriquecê-la nesse sentido.